# Jmeter: Unable to record on FF browser with HTTPS

Tags: jmeter

When I start recording, it is displaying below error:
 jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: Problem with SSL certificate? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Software caused connection abort: recv failed java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is regular situation. As you use SSL encryption, the Jmeter Proxy decrypt and re-encrypt to the server.
This is perceived from the browser as a man-in-the-middle attack (which actually is).

So, you should see an alert panel showing a message "the certification is not valid for this site", and you should accept this situation for every following page.

In some situation, the alert is intercepted by the javascript application. 
If this is the case, you have to find some other solution (and that can be really difficult in some cases).